# Laravel routes: subfolders and error in RouteCollection

Tags: laravel, routes

I have urls with subfolders:

/book/yur.voprosy/vopros-1.json

I don't count of subfolders levels which will be after /book/
My route is:

```
Route::get('/book/{file?}', 'BookController@index');
```

But if levels are more then 1 laravel returns:
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

How to fix it?

Comment: Your url says you want 1 optional parameters. So it will always stop at 1 parameters after `book`. If you have more parameters, it will always return not found. What exactly are you trying to match with your routes ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution with GET parameter! It's ok!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really do that in Laravel, because the routing system expects you to define the exact "path", so, for it to work, you would have to:

```
Route::get('/book/{folder?}/{file?}', 'BookController@index');
```

Use it in your controller this way:

```
public function index($folder = null, $file = null) { ... }
```

So you can then do

```
Route::get('/book/{f1?}/{f2?}/{f3?}/{f4?}/{f5?}/{f6?}/{f7?}', 'BookController@index');
```

And in your controller use

```
public function index() {  

    $file = implode('/', func_get_args());

}
```

$numargs = func_num_args();

Or you can do:

```
Route::get('/findbook', 'BookController@index');
```

Then hit

```
https://yourdomain.com/findbook?filename=yur.voprosy/vopros-1.json
```

And get it within your controller using

```
Input::get('filename')
```